# Increment variable for if statement

Tags: matlab, if-statement, increment

Is there a more elegant way to write this? I dont want to use a for loop

```
   if   i==1 || i==6 || i==11 || i==16 || i==21 || i==26 || i==31 || i==36
function
    end
```

basically i is the index of a vector, after each fifth element of this vector (starting with the first ) a specific function is applied. i starts with 1 and it increments after the if statement and just if it equals these values of the if condition the if statement is valid

Comment: Those numbers are seemingly arbitrary. Is there a more descriptive way of deciding or is it on some random numbers? Also, I have no idea how you'd change this to a for loop

Comment: No , basically i is the index of a vector, after each fifth element of this vector (starting with first ) a specific function is applied. 

i starts with 1 and it increments after the if statement and just if it equals these values of the if condition the if statement is valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITTED FOR MATLAB CODE OF MODULO**

```
output = mod(input, 5); //this will output 1 if it is 1, 5, 11, 16
                        //input is your 1, 5, 11, 16 etc
                        //output is the result of modulo. else it is 0, 2, 3, 4

if(output == 1)
```

---

[previous answer]

i forgot how to write this in matlab but with your values, put it this way.

if(number%5==1)

any input 1 or 6 or 11 or any else that can add 5 to it, you'll end up in 1. else it will return false

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about this, but you would tecjnically need to add a `if input<40`

Comment: if he really needs a limiter, then it will really help too :)